# Using org.json.JSONObject to accept RequestBody is not working (null value in variable)

Tags: json, spring-boot

In a spring boot prj, I am using JSONObject to accept the incomming JSON payload from the client, but the value in `userCredentials` is null. How to fix this??

The incoming payload is valid JSON. I checked it.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
...
...

@RequestMapping(value="/helloeverybody", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="text/plain")
public ResponseEntity<String> post(@RequestBody JSONObject userCredentials,
            HttpServletRequest hsr)
```

Comment: You don't need to use a `JSONObject`, you better create your own object containing the payload you're expecting.

Comment: i can not create any pojos, if you are referring to one. That will result in to lot of pojos in my project and that is not allowed for now. I got to use some generic object like `JSONObject` and then deal with hashmap conversion.

Comment: Just use a `Map` then, something like this will do `@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same and got the requestBody. The only change was of the package. I used org.json.simple.JSONObject:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
...
...

@RequestMapping(value="/helloeverybody", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="text/plain")
public ResponseEntity<String> post(@RequestBody JSONObject userCredentials,
            HttpServletRequest hsr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that using a `Map` will solve your problem. Here's an example:

```java
@RestController
public static class GenericController {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericController.class);

    @PostMapping("/generic")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> post(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) {
        payload.forEach((key, value) -> logger.info("{}={}", key, value));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

I have used `curl` to test it.

```sh
curl -i localhost:8080/generic -d '{"key":"value"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

The response in the console should be something like:

```sh
2020-11-27 19:56:57.455  INFO 67478 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] BodyMappingApplication$GenericController : key=value
```